# Invalid hash key error while integrating facebook login with android

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-android-sdk

I was displayed with a message saying " invalid hash key . the hash key ********** is not ... " . But I copied this key into the MyApp/Settings/keyhash . Yet is doesn't work .

I tried generating the hash key with the command `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`.

This generated another hash key ,even  after i updated My app with the new key . The app still does not work .

I had this app initially in an other computer ,it work fine there . Only after shifting the project to a new computer all these issues have come .

these are my logcat values :

```
07-28 13:06:40.446  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-28 13:06:40.646  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-28 13:06:40.847  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-28 13:06:41.047  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-28 13:06:41.249  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-28 13:06:41.450  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1359)
07-28 13:06:41.627  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr D/Your Tag﹕ bPx5YeVB5lOVc+oiEwo/VWuV8+k=
07-28 13:06:41.641  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr D/SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: switch
07-28 13:06:41.641  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr D/SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: foreignObject
07-28 13:06:41.641  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr D/SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: pgfRef
07-28 13:06:41.648  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr D/SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: pgf
07-28 13:06:41.664  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr D/SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: switch
07-28 13:06:41.664  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr D/SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: foreignObject
07-28 13:06:41.664  15812-15812/com.zobbr.mettl.zobbr D/SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: pgfRef
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code to generate hash key

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "Your package name", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("Your Tag", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Comment: I am getting a " PackageManager.NameNotFoundException" when I am using this

Comment: replace Your package name with your application package name

Comment: Hey , i got it to work . But this is displaying yet another hash key . I updated this on facebook , but the original error message is being show

Comment: key generated by code is : 2jmj7I5rSw0yVb/vIWAYkK/YBwk=
key generated by command is : 4+gOcIv5b9FfVQIxtVvOZQiQeoA=
key displayed on error message : bPx5YeVB5IOVc+oiEwo/VWuV8+k=

Comment: as in the error message or the logcat values . ?
the error message says " Invalid key hash . the key hash bPx5YeVB5IOVc+oiEwo/VWuV8+k=  does not match any stored key hashes . configure your app key at http://........

Comment: hey , i have added the log values . But now it is even more weird . The log value shows  bPx5YeVB5lOVc+oiEwo/VWuV8+k= but this when i try to display with a toast it shows 2jmj7I5rSw0yVb/vIWAYkK/YBwk= . both of them are updated on facebook developers

Comment: okay now it is working . but it happened after i added bPx5YeVB5lOVc+oiEwo/VWuV8+k=  twice . Weird